# RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener affects elements that are not within the function

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have successfully add the feature to my video that once I touch the screen, a skip button appears. However, I also need to add a coin icon that pops up on top of my videoView. I have been able to do this as well, but is I touch the screen, both my skip button disappears as well as my coin button. Could someone please take a look perhaps I have indulged in bad practice?

```
thisLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(tapped) {
                    skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tapped=false;// if we tap once, the button appears
                }
                else {
                    skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// tap twice button should disappear
                    tapped=true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: add full code..it seems no reason of your problem

Comment: "perhaps I have indulged in bad practice?" I'm going to use this phrase in my daily life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was foolish really. I was on relative layout, so when my coin was created for the first time, its position was determined by my skip button. Once I set my skip button to invisible, the coin button did not have button to reference too, so it disappeared. Check xml code to make sure your buttons are not attached to each other in terms of position.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it though.